# How do I skip validating global declaration issues in lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

How can I skip `Element 'baz': No matching global declaration available for the validation root., line 1` this error in particular?

I need to validate a general set of XML/XSD pairs that are not necessarily similarly composed in any way, so hardcoded/literal rules that apply to a specific XML structure do not apply.

The XSD is being produced by GMC Inspire Designer, which is generally not an XML Validator, and is very "loose" in how it checks its syntax. The global declaration issue is occurring in my local validator, but does not occur in Inspire Designer, due to its lax nature.

How can I specify against particular error sets that will be produced by `lxml`, and continue validation?

Using the following code:

```
#get a list of all files in the working directory that are .xml files
xml_files_from_cwd = [xml_f for xml_f in listdir(my_path) if isfile(join(my_path, xml_f)) 
                      and xml_f.lower().endswith(".xml")]

xml_validator = etree.XMLSchema(file= my_path)

for xml in xml_files_from_cwd:
    recovering_parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
    xml_file = etree.parse(my_path + "/" +xml, parser=recovering_parser)

    successful = False 
    try:
        successful = xml_validator.assertValid(xml_file)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"File not valid: {e}")
    
    if successful:
        print(f"No errors detected in {xml}.")
```

I am having issues validating an XML file where the XML looks, generally like this:

```
<baz>
  <bar BEGIN="1">
  ... [repeating elements here]
  </bar>
</baz>
```

And an XSD that follows this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="foo">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xsd:element name="bar" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  .... [repeating elements here]
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that your document is in fact not valid ('baz' outer element instead of 'foo'), but other than that it may be valid, and you want the validator to only report any further issues? How about simply changing the outer element from 'baz' to 'foo' after loading, but  before validation?

Comment: @Grismar You are correct- that would work in a singular context, but doing spot-checking for any singular file implementation would be a lot of wasted time/extra effort due to the number of implementations involved. 

Unless you are suggesting I peel the structure back layer by layer until it validates? Honestly, I just need it to continue to validate until the end of the file and spit out all possible issues.

Comment: The problem is that what you are proposing might work for simple problems like a misnamed element, but what if 'baz' was missing altogether, or if there was an alternative for 'foo' in its place. Validation *has* to stop on the first error, because anything that follows may or may not be valid based on choices about how you would fix the error, if that makes sense. Not so much in this trivial case, but absolutely in general.

Comment: @Grismar I hear you. It's really an issue, because Inspire Designer does not produce any error context when it fails its files, and seems to perform fairly irregularly in its approach/consistency of results. Namespacing and a handful of attributes seem to spuriously cause issues. Trying to find an adequate solution when I have no access to the logic itself.

Comment: If you want to toss that into an answer, I'll mark it as complete and that will be that. @Grismar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that validation relies on the whole document being valid.

For example, if your document would be valid for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType>
       <xs:choice>
         <xs:element name="bar">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element name="baz"/>
                    <xs:element name="qux"/>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="quux">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="qux"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
       </xs:choice>    
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This document would be a problem:

```
<foo>
  <quuz>
    <qux/>
    ...
  </quuz>
</foo>
```

Should `quuz` be a `bar` or a `quux`?

You might be able to tell from what follows, but then you'll have to backtrack to each decision every time you run into a problem and try another decision at that point.

This gets very complicated very quickly, as something being valid may depend on its contents, its structure, its attribute values etc. Very soon, you'll have so many options to test that it becomes impossible - you can even think of situations where the number of choices is practically infinite, so you'd have to include very complicated logic to come up with a valid value.

In simple cases, like the example you showed where only the outer tag may be misnamed, you could simply fix that error in memory and retry validation. But that's not a method that scales to the whole document.

Note: in real life scenarios you may actually know and expect what's coming in and you can follow a strategy of trying validation and if it fails, repeatedly fixing the problem because you *do* know what the options are, until you reach the end of the document. My answer only wants to make the point that there's no general solution here.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the answer to this question, "Can we continue to validate a file past an initial failure condition", is no, as there's no guarantee whether any further validation would yield positive results beyond simple/trivial cases.